# How does confirmDismiss know where the boolean comes from?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following Widget definition:

```
class CartItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String productId;
  final double price;
  final int quantity;
  final String title;

  CartItem(
    this.id,
    this.productId,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.title,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(id),
      background: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
      ),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      confirmDismiss: (direction) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Are you sure?'),
                content: Text(
                  'Do you want to remove the item from the cart?',
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('No'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(ctx).pop(false);
                    },
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Yes'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(ctx).pop(true);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        );
      },
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).removeItem(productId);
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text('\$$price'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(title),
            subtitle: Text('Total: \$${(price * quantity)}'),
            trailing: Text('$quantity x'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Consider the method `confirmDismiss`, it has the type definition of:

```
typedef ConfirmDismissCallback = Future<bool> Function(DismissDirection direction);
```

The `showDialog` returns `Future<T>`, where the `T` has to be a `Boolean` to satisfy the type constraint of `confirmDismiss`.

The `Boolean` is returned by `Navigator.of(ctx).pop(false)` or `Navigator.of(ctx).pop(true)` depends on user interaction.

I am confused about how the `Boolean` can be returned by `Navigator.of(ctx).pop(false)` or `Navigator.of(ctx).pop(true)`. It seems like magic to me.

Comment: Are you still confused by this?  I've reworded my answer a bit to try to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[`showDialog`'s documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) states:

> Returns a `Future` that resolves to the value (if any) that was passed to `Navigator.pop` when the dialog was closed.

If you look at the implementation for `showDialog` (and really for [`showGeneralDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/showGeneralDialog.html), you'll see that it internally pushes a route onto the `Navigator`. [`Navigator.push`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) itself returns a `Future<T>` that at some later time will resolve to the value passed to the closing `Navigator.pop`.

So `showDialog` creates an `AlertDialog` whose buttons trigger `Navigator.pop` with a `bool`, depending on which button is pushed.  Pushing on a button completes the `Navigator.push`'s `Future` and allows the value to be returned by the callback passed to the `Dismissible.confirmDismiss`.  Note that `Dismissible` itself doesn't know where the `bool` returned by the callback came from, nor does it care.